# Boot screen hangs even after factory reset

Tags: boot-loop, motorola-droid, motorola-droid-razr

My Droid Razr XT910 was constantly booting and after a forced reboot still hangs here. As a next step I wiped out the data via the boot menu, i.e. a factory reset. But the phone still hangs with the boot logo. My phone is stock, not rooted. I let it constantly load over night, until the battery finished. Two days ago I tried the factory reset, but it didn't result in showing the home screen. I did several factory resets just to check. Is there any way to let the phone boot again?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried removing the SDCard to see whether it boots without? Rare cases, but a damaged card *might* cause this. You could also try to boot it "completely bare" (i.e. removing the SIM card as well), but from your description my guess is rather the SDCard. If all that doesn't help, I can only think of the service point to check.

Comment: Did you clear the dalvik cache?

Comment: Yes, I removed the SDCard. Still hangs. And I already cleared the cache.

Comment: Roman, has this issue solved for you? Have you had the service take a look at it, maybe?

Comment: The issue was resolved by sending the device back. Service couldn't resolve it either.